# Google Identity Toolkit configuration does not provide LinkedIn login

Tags: linkedin-api, google-openid, google-identity-toolkit, google-identity

Anyone have any clue why Google's Identity Toolkit does not have option for configuring LinkedIn Login?

If we have to add LInkedIn to an existing Identity Toolkit what is the best way to do it?

Any pointers will be highly appreciated!

Thanks,